# Failing to access DVD-A disc

Tags: windows-7, dvd

I have a [DVD-Audio disc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD-Audio) which is also a CD. When inserting this into Windows, it comes up as an audio disc. Can I tell Windows to address the disc as a DVD and not a CD?

**Update** this is my bad. The disc is [Steely Dan Gaucho DVD-A](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0001JXQDI), and loading it into my computer does mount the disc as:

[image: DVD-A mounted]

I can confirm VideoLAN can access the disc, but at the wrong sample rate.

[image: VideoLAN playing the disc]

When trying to extract the audio files, [DVD-Audio Extractor](http://www.dvdae.com/dvdae) fails to load the disc.

[image: DVD-Audio extractor]

Comment: Can you share the purpose of that? It might be easier to find an answer when we know what you are trying to do - maybe it's also possible while your DVD is being recognized as CD.

Comment: If you're trying to recover files, [IsoBuster](http://www.isobuster.com/isobuster.php) (shareware) might be something worth checking out.

Comment: Are there files on this disc that you want to access?  What about video?  Is it a "combo" disc with DVD-Audio and Video output?

Comment: Is there still a question post-update?

Answer (score 2):

What a mess. I'm learning a lot myself here. As far as I can deduce from literature, a PC DVD drive *ought* to be able to read DVD-A content. After all, it's just a bunch of files.

Firstly, never mind what Windows says about your DVD-A. Windows is dumb in that respect, so ignore it. What you need is software that can *properly* deal with DVD-A content. It turns out that [VLC might not be as capable as we thought](http://www.avsforum.com/forum/112-surround-music-formats/1488273-issue-vlc-dvd.html).

Give [Foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) a go. It is your best bet. I don't use it much myself these days, but it will definitely cope with DVD-A with [this plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dvdadecoder/). You may also be able to rip the audio streams too.

Answer (score 1):

Try [DVD-Audio Explorer](http://www.videohelp.com/software/DVD-Audio-Explorer). It's designed to specifically deal with DVD-Audio discs. I compiled and used this on a Mac a while ago, and I'm looking at the Windows binary running in [Wine](https://www.winehq.org) on a Mac now, and that seems to work as well.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of discs should in theory be playable from a Home-Theater CD/DVD player. I Never had one of these things that made no problems.

If you want to play them on the PC, they usually come with their own player because they have protected the hell out of them. 
You will probably find and installer from the mid-90's on the disc somewhere and you will be lucky if it works at all and doesn't install some kind of trojan on your PC.

- Backup the whole thing with [MakeMKV](http://www.makemkv.com/download/), that should remove the copyright nonsense from the disc. Make an MKV Video file with [Freemake Video Converter](http://www.freemake.com/de/free_video_converter/) out of the Video part of the disc.
- Now you should be able to rip the audio tracks with [DVD-Audio Explorer](http://www.videohelp.com/software/DVD-Audio-Explorer) by navigating through the rip-path.
- Throw away that nonsense waste of plastic and alluminum!